# Automating Django documentation with Sphinx

Tags: django, python-sphinx

I am using Sphinx to generate documentation for a Django project, and it is working really well. However it seems to be necessary to write the .rst files yourself, and once that is done, sphinx will compile the documentation from the docstrings when you run make HTML.

My questions is:
I am looking for the docs to reflect new additions to the project automatically without having to edit the .rst files manually.

As everything in Django always seems so simple, I find it odd that you have to create the rst files for the entire project manually, I would have thought that there is something that already exists, that automatically inspects the structure of the project, and builds the rst's  from that.

I have looked at this project http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-sphinx-autodoc/0.0 which looks promising, but I am surprised that there is not something more mature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a while, [Sphinx apidoc](http://sphinx-doc.org/man/sphinx-apidoc.html) is bundled with Sphinx. This can create a full set of `.rst` files for you.

It becomes more of a problem if you want to document all the various django applications that you use in one site (this seems to be what you want). Sphinx apidoc wants a bunch of directories to scan for python packages.